# angular2 event subscribe gives undefined

Tags: angular

I have a service which emits an event as following:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmitService {

  private goalId = new Subject<number>();

  goalId$ = this.goalId.asObservable();

  emitGoalId(goalId: number) {
    this.goalId.next(goalId);
  }
}
```

I have a List component which does the following:

```
import{ EmitService } from '../../services/emiter.service'

@Component({
selector: 'goal-list',
templateUrl: './list.html',
styleUrls: ['./list.scss'],
providers:[EmitService]
})
export class GoalListComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private emitService: EmitService
        ){}
editGoals(goalId){

        this.editIdeasStepper=true;

        //emit goaldId so that it can be access in subgoals to load those subgoals
        this.emitService.emitGoalId(goalId);

    }
}
```

I have another component `SubGoalComponent` which subscribes to this event:

```
import { EmitService } from '../../services/emiter.service';

@Component({
selector: 'sub-goal',
templateUrl: './sub_goal.html',
styleUrls: ['./sub_goal.scss'],
providers:[EmitService]
})
export class SubGoalComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private elRef:ElementRef, 
        private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef,
        private emitService: EmitService
        ){}
    ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.emitService.goalId$.subscribe(
            goalId => {
                alert(goalId)
                this.goalId=goalId;
                alert("Subgoal " + this.goalId)
        }
     )
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
    this.emitService.goalId$.subscribe(
        goalId => {

            this.goalId=goalId;
            alert("Subgoal " + this.goalId)
        }
        )

    console.log("SubGoal ngOnInIt")
    console.log("Subgoal " + this.goalId)
}
```

`SubGoalComponent`is conditionally loaded in `GoalListComponent's` template as following:

```
<div *ngIf="showCardListComponent" class="mdl-grid">
    <!-- actual card list -->
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col">
        <div class="goal-list-card mdl-card" *ngFor="let idea of ideas| values; let j = index;">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{idea.Title}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions">
                <button (click)="editGoals(j)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col" *ngIf="editIdeasStepper">

        <ul #editIdeaStepper class="mdl-stepper mdl-stepper--horizontal" id="demo-stepper-nonlinear">
           <!-- Sub problems tab -->
            <li class="mdl-step">
                <span class="mdl-step__label">
                    <span class="mdl-step__title">
                        <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Sub-problems</span>
                        <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Uncover sub-problems</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <!-- insert sub-goal component instead of writing html here -->
                <div class="mdl-step__content">
                    <sub-goal></sub-goal>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-step__actions">

                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Here in my alert I get `undefined`. Why it is happening?

Comment: Where do you provide the `EmitService` to these components? Are you sure they are using the same instance of this class?

Comment: In both these classes I just imported it and then initialized in constructors

Comment: Can you include the `@Component` part of the classes in your question please?

Comment: I updated my question with @component decorator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `providers:[EmitService]` from the components and add it to your `app.module`s `@NgModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [EmitService],
  ...
})
```

The reason it's `undefined` is that you are providing different instances of this service by initializing them in the `@Component` annotation of each component. If you provide it inside a module that contains these components then they will have the same instance of this service.

Comment: Let me try this. In app.modules's providers=[] section?

Comment: I tried this, but where I subscribe in my SubGoal component in ngOnInIt or  ngAfterViewInit it doesn't alert, so I guess that code is not being executed. My subGoal component is loaded on *ngIf condition in ListComponent's template, could that be reason somehow?

Comment: Put a `console.log();` on `ngOnInIt` to find out if its loading or not. I don't know where you define `showCardListComponent`. But you were saying that your alert was undefined, did moving the provider cause you to not see the alert?

Comment: Yes console statements in `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngOnInit` are printing but alert is not. And yea this happened after I moved Service from component's providers to app module.

Comment: What I realized is that when you were providing the service in the components and not in the module, you shouldn't even be seeing undefined since the subject instances are not the same..

Comment: Okay it is working but there is a tricky problem. The alert fires when I click editGoals() from List Components's template event after subGoal component is loaded

Comment: When should it alert? You are emiting the value inside `editGoals()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139896/discussion-between-nitish-and-echonax).

Comment: So, the problem was I had to emit it after upgrading the DOM.